# Server Implementation in C

Tags: html, c, parsing, server, segmentation-fault

I'm currently working on a server which is part of my course requirement. The specs require me to parse a request line and store the appropriate data as absolute path (abs_path) and query.

Here is my code:

```
bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)
```

{
    int space = 0;

```
if (strchr(line, '"') != NULL)
{
    error(400);
    return false;
}

for (int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (line[i] == ' ')
    {
        space++;
    }
}

if (space != 2)
{    
    error(400);
    return false;
}

if (strncmp("GET ", line, 4) != 0)
{    
    error(405);
    return false;
}

line = strchr(line, ' ');
line++;

if (strncmp("/", line, 1) != 0)
{
    error(501);
    return false;
}

int j = 0;
int k = 4;

while (line[k] != ' ')
{
    int m = k;
    abs_path[j] = line[k];
    j++;
    if (line[k+1] == '?')
    {
        abs_path[j] = '\0';
        int l = 0;
        m = k+2;

        while (line[m] != ' ')
        {
            query[l] = line[m];
            l++;
            m++;
        }
        if (line[m] == ' ' && l == 0)
        {
            query[0] = '\0';
        }
    }
    k = m;
    k++;
    if (line[k] == ' ')
    {
        abs_path[j] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}

char* last = strrchr(line, ' ');
last++;
if (strcmp("HTTP/1.1", last) != 0)
{
    error(505);
    return false;
}
free(abs_path);
return true;
```

}

I keep getting a segmentation fault with this. After some debugging, I've found the segmentation fault to be eliminated if I declare, on line 20, abs_path as an array instead of a pointer. However, it is necessary for me to declare abs_path as a pointer, so I need another solution to this. Can someone explain to me what exactly I am doing wrong with regards to strings and their handling?

I have been quite rusty with this due to personal reasons so pardon me if I misunderstand something basic.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: better if you paste relevant code snippet, here.

Comment: I'll do that from now, ty

Comment: @RedAlert There's also cs50.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please follow the rules and post you code **in the question itself**! Not for the future, but to prevent this one from bein closed.

Comment: you can edit your question and do it now,, my proxy is blocking access to that link. But in most situations arrays behave exactly as pointers. Avoid using `malloc` unless 1) memory must persist outside of the function. 2) You don't know how much memory you will need until runtime. 3) You need "a lot" of memory. Just easier and safer to not deal with memory management unless you have to.

Comment: @yano: "arrays behave exactly as pointers" - No, they don't! They are just **converted to** pointers for most operators.

Comment: @Olaf thus the similar behavior

Comment: @yano: Read my comment carefully again and think about it! An array does never behave like a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf They do when passed to a function, when dereferenced. I'm not saying they are the same thing,, I'm saying they behave similarly in certain situations. I can't see the OP's code, but I doubt there will be much of a difference for what he wants to do between `char abs_path[256];` and `char* abs_path = malloc(256);`

Comment: They are also converted for e.g. the `[]`-operator and all but exactly  three operators. That's exactly why they **cannot** "behave similarly". What you observe is the behaviour of the pointer, not the array.

Comment: have edited the main post, thank you

Comment: @Olaf Sure, practical behavior after the conversion. If I have a function `print_string(char* string, int length)`, I don't care if I pass a `char[]` or `char*` to it. The `char[]` decays to a pointer and my string gets printed, no?

Comment: You cannot have an array object with unspecified length. And no, that is not the same, as such function arguments **are** pointers internally. Not converted ones. For _actual parameters_ it is wrong, as you never pass an array to a function. Please do some research; this is the core to understanding arrays and their usage in C.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory for the char*.  An array does this automatically during compile time. Try malloc.

```
char* abs_path = 0;
abs_path = (char*)malloc(256);
```

Essentially, malloc performs an operating system call to reserve sequential memory from the heap. The argument of malloc is how many bytes to reserve. Therefore, you should be aware that the example above enables the abs_path char* to point to a string that is at max 255 characters (leaving 1 byte for the null character '\0'). Don't let your code write more than 255 characters or you will overwrite other data in memory, which is why you received a seg-fault before.

As someone else noted, you should DEFINITELY free up memory reserved dynamically with malloc.

```
free(abs_path);
```

Comment: also there is no need for casting malloc result in C.

Comment: Thanks for the input @GiorgiMoniava. I included the cast in hopes it would help clarify what is happening here, but you are correct.

Comment: What is `null`?

Comment: @Olaf null represents zero. I'll modify this since some compilers do not define null.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner
Thank you very much! It seems to be working in the test code I just submitted, but not in the actual program where abs_path is already malloced to be of a particular size.

Apologies for the pastebin, code doesn't quite fit over here: http://pastebin.com/W4GY0sHU

Comment: @CaitLANJenner: **Every** C implementation has to provide the `NULL` macro (there is no `null` whatever). If you have a compiler which does not, it is a signal of severe flaws. Delete it and get a correct one. Don't invent new nomenclature for standard names.

Comment: @RedAlert I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "It seems to be working in the test code ... but not in the actual program."  When you compile and run your test code do you still receive a seg-fault?

Comment: I have edited the main post with revised code from the actual program. Might I get a solution to why exactly I am getting none of the outputs shown within this loop?

Comment: @CaitLANJenner, No I do not get a segfault in the test code. That issue has been cleared. Ty for that

Comment: @RedAlert: See [ask]. If you did not provide a [mcve], edit your question! As others and me already stated: Show the code in quetion **in the question**!

Comment: @CaitLANJenner: Undefined behaviour does not necessarily result in a crash or segfault! That's one major reason trial&error in C is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf, I agree with you 100%. However, the person who posted this question initially stated they were receiving a seg-fault. I'm simply stating improper use of a character pointer likely caused that, and I'm happy to know that issue has since been resolved. None of your feedback appears to be positive nor does it seem to relate to the question that was originally asked. Perhaps instead of complaining about null versus NULL versus 0, or other semantics, you should provide an answer yourself.